# What is the length in bytes of the Android_id?

Tags: java, android, mobile

What is the typical length of the Secure.Android_ID ? In my tests I only came across these strings being 16 bytes in length, but want to make sure because I am building a system that needs to distinguish between the Android_ID and the Device ID from Telephonymanager because our API uses the same GET parameter for both the Android_ID and the Device_ID.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID

Answer (score 5):

The docs say it is "64-bit number (as a hex string)".  Each hex digit represents 4 bits, so it will be a 16 character `String`.  That should be true across all currently published APIs >= 3.  Google could always deprecate that and change it in the future.

Comment: I've personally seen an Android ID that is only 15 digits long.  It seems that leading zeros may be omitted.